# I have an angularjs service function to test that a $(window).trigger was called with parameters (using jasmine)

Tags: triggers, window, mocking, angularjs, jasmine

I'm new to jasmine and using angularjs as a framework.
How can i test that a `$(window).trigger` "haveBeenCalledWith":

Code to test (it's a function in an angularjs service):

```
start: function (serverUrl, callbackFunc) {
                  // initialize communication manager and when ready start the worklist server
                  commManager.initAsync(serverUrl, function (isConnected) {
                      if (isConnected) {
                          var msgHeader = new protocolMessageHeader(userSessionGuid, messageCommandName.START_WL_SESSION + "_RQ");
                          var dataSet = { $type: 10, UserSessionGuid: userSessionGuid, WLSessionGuid: wlSessionGuid };
                          commManager.sendMessage(new protocolMessage(msgHeader, dataSet), function (data) {                              
                              if (callbackFunc) {
                                  callbackFunc(data);
                              }
                          });
                      } else {                          
                          **$(window).trigger(events.onShowModalDialog, {
                              title: "Worklist Server Error",
                              body: "Can not establish connection to Worklist server",
                              type: generalStatusEnum.ERROR
                          });**
                      }
                  });
              }
```

I made `isConnected` to be false and i want to test that `$(window).trigger` was called with the above parameters

Answer (score 0):

Its always a problem when your code to test depends on other libraries/frameworks. So in your case, using $(window) as a global event bus is the root that it makes the code hard to test. There are some solution for this:

Let `$()` return a mock where you can spy on the `trigger` method. This will make your test code a bit more verbose but you can keep your actual code:

```
var trigger = jasmine.createSpy();
spyOn(window, '$').andReturn({trigger: trigger});

yourLib.start('url', callback);

expect(trigger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(events.onShowModalDialog, {
   title: "Worklist Server Error",
   body: "Can not establish connection to Worklist server",
   type: generalStatusEnum.ERROR
 });
```

In your example its easy cause you use `$` only once, but think about having different uses of jquery in function will it make really hard or impossible to test the function.

A better way would be to pass the event bus into your function, or in the constructor of class. So for example your start function could look like this:

```
start: function (serverUrl, callbackFunc, eventBus) {
  commManager.initAsync(serverUrl, function (isConnected) {
    if (isConnected) {
      var msgHeader = new protocolMessageHeader(userSessionGuid, messageCommandName.START_WL_SESSION + "_RQ");
      var dataSet = { $type: 10, UserSessionGuid: userSessionGuid, WLSessionGuid: wlSessionGuid };
      commManager.sendMessage(new protocolMessage(msgHeader, dataSet), function (data) {                              
        if (callbackFunc) {
          callbackFunc(data);
        }
      });
    } else {                          
      eventBus.trigger(events.onShowModalDialog, {
        title: "Worklist Server Error",
        body: "Can not establish connection to Worklist server",
        type: generalStatusEnum.ERROR
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And the test would look like this:

```
var trigger = jasmine.createSpy();

yourLib.start('url', callback, trigger);

expect(trigger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(events.onShowModalDialog, {
   title: "Worklist Server Error",
   body: "Can not establish connection to Worklist server",
   type: generalStatusEnum.ERROR
 });
```

**Edit**
Just realize that all your code is wrapped in a callback, so you have also spy on `commManager.initAsync`, and call the callback:

```
spyOn(commManager, 'initAsync');

var callback = commManager.initAsync.mostRecentCall.args[1];
callback();
```